# Cannot send keystrokes to VM on hyper-V using JAVA

Tags: java, ssh, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have to send keystrokes to virtual machine. Task is repetitive(I have to do it 3-4 times a day), but can be easily simulated by sending keystrokes. *Actually my VMs have only terminal window (linux based) with SSH session running.*

I wrote a small java test program to send the keystrokes.

```
public class TestRobot1 {

    static int keyInput[] = {
        KeyEvent.VK_H, KeyEvent.VK_E,
        KeyEvent.VK_L, KeyEvent.VK_L,
        KeyEvent.VK_O, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Robot robot =  new Robot();
        for(int i = 0; i < keyInput.length; i++){
             robot.keyPress(keyInput[i]);
             robot.delay(10);
             robot.keyRelease(keyInput[i]);
             robot.delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

This program runs successfully on **Notepad**, **VM started in Oracle Virtual Box**, **and accessed through SSH Session**. But it **doesn't run when VM is started from hyper-V**, though I can SSH to that, and then I can run the program.

*I have to select the window, on which this should run, that's why I have included 5 sec wait, so that I can select the correct window in the time. I know that is not very good but, it's a test program.*

Comment: Try to increase delay after `keyPress()`

Comment: Already tried that. No Success. Moreover if that had been the case, atleast 1st key stroke would have been registered.

Comment: Where do you perform the click when you focus the remote desktop window: on the window header or on notepad running on remote machine? Try to click on notepad and even try to type manually to be sure that it is indeed in focus.

Comment: Tried that just now. Still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not worked with hiper-v, but I worked with regular remote desktop. I however performed click that makes focus on window using the robot itself. Try this technique. For reference take a look on https://github.com/alexradzin/TypeToPaste

Here is the TypeToPaste site: https://sites.google.com/site/typetopaste/

I recommend to download this application and try it. If it works, examine its code. Otherwise I am sorry...

Please let me know how is it going anyway. I am very curious...

Comment: Your given program works. Thanks! Now I have to see whether I can use it directly for my needs or should I go through you code. Sorry for late reply, but I have access to hyper-v only in my office.

Comment: NP, glad to hear that you have a progress. Learn the code. It is not too complicated and IMHO well documented. Do not hesitate to ask questions if you have problems.